# Change the third str of each subset as int

Tags: python, list, int

I want to make every third string of a list as number
for example:

```
stat = [[1 , '2', '3'], [34, '32', '4'], [45, '21', '56']
```

to

```
stat = [[1 , '2', 3], [34, '32', 4], [45, '21', 56]
```

I tried

```
for i in stat:
    i[2]= int(i[2])
```

Can some one help?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me (with proper indentation).

Comment: What you tried should be sufficient. What is the problem?

Comment: The loop looks fine. Your nested list declaration is missing one closing bracket though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often it is easier to build a new list than to modify an existing one.

I would use iterable unpacking to unpack each element of your sublists into three names, then use `int` on the third one.

```
>>> stat = [[1 , '2', '3'], [34, '32', '4'], [45, '21', '56']]
>>> stat = [[a, b, int(c)] for a, b, c in stat]
>>> stat
>>> [[1, '2', 3], [34, '32', 4], [45, '21', 56]]
```

This list comprehension builds a new list and reassigns the name `stat`.

However, your original code *should* work fine:

```
>>> stat = [[1 , '2', '3'], [34, '32', '4'], [45, '21', '56']]
>>> 
>>> for i in stat:
...:    i[2] = int(i[2])
...:    
>>> stat
>>> [[1, '2', 3], [34, '32', 4], [45, '21', 56]]
```

This modifies `stat` in place. I suggest using a better name than `i`, for example `sublist`. `i` makes me think of integers.